# Integrating a TypeScript Package with SCSS into a React Project: Seeking Best Practices

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a local React (with typescript) package that contains both TypeScript (*.tsx) and SCSS. I'm attempting to integrate this package into another React project. I've tried multiple approaches, but each has its own set of challenges:

**Compiled Version:** When I compile the package and then use it in my React project, I encounter issues related to SCSS, preventing it from functioning as expected.

**Raw** .tsx Files: Using the raw .tsx files (i.e., uncompiled), I find myself having to make complex Webpack configurations in my main project, which I'd like to avoid.

I'm looking for a straightforward method or best practices to seamlessly integrate this custom package into my React project. Does anyone have experience or suggestions on this topic?

Thanks!

Comment: what are the issues regarding SCSS?